# Solving second order PDE using Laplace transforms. $u_{t}(x,t)-u_{x}(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$ with $u(x,0)=\cos(2x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am asked to use the Laplace transform to solve the initial value problem for the advection-diffusion equation:

$$u_{t}(x,t)-u_{x}(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$$ with $u(x,0)=\cos(2x)$

Taking the Laplace transform of this I got:

$$s\widetilde{u}(x,s)-u(x,0)-\widetilde{u}_{x}(x,s) = \widetilde{u}_{xx}(x,s)$$

$$ \implies \widetilde{u}_{xx}(x,s) + \widetilde{u}_{x}(x,s) - s\widetilde{u}(x,s) = -\cos(2x) $$

And I found the auxiliary equation to be: $λ^2+λ-s$

and by completing the square I got the general solution to be:

$$\widetilde{u}(x,s)= A(s)e^{[(s+1/4)^{1/2}-1/2]x} + B(s)e^{[-(s+1/4)^{1/2}-1/2]x} +\cos(2x)$$

I'm not sure about this but I think we assume that the equation is bounded so $A$ and $B$ are equivalent to $0$. It does not say this in the question so I may be wrong.

I'm not sure what to do after this point, I'm assuming we have to use the Laplace transform but I think I'm missing a step or 2. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's hard to simplify further without more information. Do you have boundary conditions? What is the domain of the solution?

Comment: Also, your particular solution is incorrect

Comment: Your particular solution is incorrect, but you are correct in your intuition that the solution must be bounded as $x\to\pm\infty$ and as $s\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ 
\widetilde{u}_{xx}(x,s) + \widetilde{u}_{x}(x,s) - s\widetilde{u}(x,s) = -\cos(2x) 
$$

is a linear non homogeneous DE which solution can be represented as

$$
\widetilde{u}(x,s) = \widetilde{u}_h(x,s)+\widetilde{u}_p(x,s)
$$

The homogeneous solution is

$$
\widetilde{u}_h(x,s)=A(s)e^{[(s+1/4)^{1/2}-1/2]x} + B(s)e^{[-(s+1/4)^{1/2}-1/2]x}
$$

and the particular is

$$
\widetilde{u}_p(x,s) = \frac{4 ((s + 4)\cos (2 x)-2 \sin (2 x))}{\left((9+2s)^2-(4s+1)\right)}
$$

obtained after the substitution of $\widetilde{u}_p(x,s) = C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)$ into the DE.